# PHP foreach nested loops creates a very big amount of strings

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, loops, foreach

I'd like to loop trough 2 arrays and show the output using console.log() function.

```
$fermos = array(1, 2, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25);
$gyvuliu_tipai = array(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);

foreach ($gyvuliu_tipai as $value) {
    foreach ($fermos as $value2) {
    switch ($value) {
        case 1:
            $ferma = '/produkcija/';
            break;
        case 2:
            $ferma = '/kiaulide/';
            break;
        case 3:
            $ferma = '/avide/';
            break;
        case 4:
            $ferma = '/karvide/';
            break;
        case 5:
            $ferma = '/lamu-ferma/';
            break;
        case 6:
            $ferma = '/drambliu-ferma/';
            break;
    } ?>
    <script>console.log('<?php echo $ferma . $value2; ?>');</script>    
<?php } } ?>
```

Expected output would be:

```
/produkcija/1
/produkcija/2
/kiaulide/5
/avide/10
/karvide/15
/lamu-ferma/20
/drambliu-ferma/25
```

But somehow it outputs this:
[image]

Could anyone tell me what is going on here? Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want a nested loop...use the index of the `$fermos` loop to get associated value of `$gyvuliu_tipai` array for the switch

```
 foreach ($fermos as $index => $value2) {
    switch ($gyvuliu_tipai[$index]) {
      ....
    }
 }
```

Or to make it even simpler without switch:

```
$gyvuliu_tipai= array('produkcija','kiaulide','avide', 'karvide','lamu-ferma','drambliu-ferma');

foreach ($fermos as $index => $value2) {
   $ferma = '/' . $gyvuliu_tipai[$index] . '/';
   ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the second option doesn't suit my case because the value is stored in the database and I should change the database records in case to do it but thank you for your efforts to the second option :)